# calendar control: MS Ajax vs. jQuery

Tags: asp.net

I need to put a calendar control on an aspx page. I can choose among the multiple jQuery plug-ins or use the calendar control that comes with the Ajax Control Toolkit.

What's going to be easier/faster/better?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to stick to jQuery, as for me.. Ajax Control Toolkit based upon ASP.net AJAX Framework, which is a slowly dying. Microsoft contribute and support jQuery now :)

Answer (score 1):

From my experience Ajax Control Toolkit is better for ASP.Net WebForms and jQuery is better for MVC projects. Best way is use one approach and do not mix them in one solution.